# Whats wrong with my delete core object method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a method that is called in the app delegate by the UIViewControllers which deletes the core object that matches the selected objects name.  It deletes from the UIListView which is correct and the refresh method (which checks core data for all objects)doesn't bring it back to the list view.  However, when I close the application and restart it it brings back the just deleted objects.  Here is the method:

```
-(void)deleteObject:(NSString *)configName
{
    //Generates the request context for core data
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"StoredSetups" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(config_name = %@)", configName];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (objects.count == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Matches");
    }
    else
    {
        matches = objects[0];
        [context deleteObject:matches];
    }
}
```

Any help or feed back will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to save the context after delete like this :

```
if (objects.count == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Matches");
    }
    else
    {
        matches = objects[0];
        [context deleteObject:matches];
        [context save:&error];
    }
```